# syntax error: operand expected (error token is "+ ") in bash

Tags: bash, sh

I am trying to calculate the sum of numbers entered via command line to my script file. Here  is my code

```
#!/bin/bash
for ((i=0;i<=$#;i++))
do
sum=$(($i + $sum))
done
echo $sum | bc
```

My terminal input is

```
bash file.sh 1 2
```

So the output should be 3 but I am getting

```
 syntax error: operand expected (error token is "+ ")
```

Comment: `$i` does not mean "the value of argument `i`". It means "the value of the variable named `i`. So you're just going to add up the first `argc` integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual error reason is because of uninitialized variable `sum` going through the first iteration of the loop. Initialize the variable before entering the loop.

Also a major logical flaw is that you are not even iterating over the input arguments, but just over the counter `i` which will produce incorrect results if you pass arguments other than `1 2` from the command-line.

You need to pass over the actual arguments `argc` and `argv` (arg count and arg vector: for understanding purposes only) and you don't need `bc` at all

```
argc=$#
argv=("$@")

sum=0
for ((i=0; i<${argc}; i++)); do
    sum=$((${argv[i]} + $sum))
done
```

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I was getting 3 every time, but your code is working fine.

Comment: There is no reason to define `argc` or `argv`, or to use this loop. Just use `for i in "$@"; do sum=$((i+sum)); done` (or even `for i; do`).

Comment: @chepner: Absolutely true! Just wanted to show the OP how the arguments are processed in a familiar way. Used the variables so it will be easy for them to grasp!

Answer (score 1):

To loop over all command line arguments, you can use the simplified form of the shell `for` statement:

```
sum=0
for i do
  ((sum += i))
done
```

`((sum+=i))` is accepted by bash and many other shells; for a Posix-compatible shell, you can use arithmetic expansion with the `:` builtin:

```
: $((sum += i))
```

Comment: `sum+=` appends a string, rather than incrementing `sum`, unless you set the integer attribute (`declare -i sum`).

Comment: @chepner: quite right; I shouldn't answer questions in the middle of the night. Changed it to an arithmetic evaluation.